# How do get accurate physics of a spinning object within another to show gyroscopic precession

Tags: physics

I am trying to recreate [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHYwHvmRH4c) where a spinning wheel inside an object causes gyroscopic precession. I have tried to model the spinning part as a completely separate object from the holder but the contact point is too small and the parts blow up. I have tried to do a hinge connecting the two but it doesn't seem as though they communicate any momentum data across the hinge. [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/bjl2fo/gyroscope_with_blender_physics/) exactly covers what I am going for and someone created an example, but it is no longer available and there are no instructions.

I imagine there should be a way to tell blender to not worry about collisions between the two objects (a la hinge) and for the angular momentum of the spinner to influence the holder, but I can't figure it out. Thank you!

[Here's a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pwss6s6rajebs0f/gyroscope.blend?dl=0) to the current file.

Comment: show us what you tried so far. e.g. with blend file

Comment: I just updated a link to it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my very late answer, and it isn't really an answer but some hints:

1. in a physics simulation you should always apply scale and rotation
2. whenever your object hasn't a very simple geometry like a sphere or a box, you have to use "mesh" as shape, else the simulation will fail
3. make sure all face orientations of your objects are right
4. lower margin to 0 in rigid body object
5. try to use a geometry which is as easy as possible, yours is pretty complicated. I am pretty sure, sometimes the video makers are using much simpler objects, do the physics with them and then just make them invisible and parent more complicated geometry objects to the "ready" animation. So don't let you fool by yt videos....