# Spinner with precession

Tags: animation, transforms, transform-orientation

Trying to create a spinner with precession. But without physics, just an animation.
So, the object is rotating around the Z axis. At the same time, the upper end of the Z axis should draw a circle in the space (I should be able to set this angle beta), and the lower end of the Z axis should stay at the XY = (0,0) (center of rotation in XY plane).

The periods of precession and rotation of the object are different.
[image: Fig_1]

Haw can I do this ?

PS
There is a similar post [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224165/how-do-get-accurate-physics-of-a-spinning-object-within-another-to-show-gyroscop), but there is no solution and it is done with the physics.

I try to do this with delta-transform but in such way I get precession impacted the rotation speed. This is not good, these processes are separeted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. give your spinner a z-rotation -> linear extrapolation:

[image]

2. move the cursor to the bottom of your object, add an empty

[image]

3. select your spinner, shift select the empty ->keep transform without inverse

[image]

4. now rotate your empty on x (or y) as you want

[image]

6. now give a z rotation to your empty as you like with linear extrapolation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is what I need.
How can I do Point 3 by scripting?

Comment: you are welcome....i have no idea. I would have to research that too....maybe just ask another question? you can ask as often as you like and there are some great python experts here!

Comment: @Chris _Set Parent to > Object_ is sufficient for this setup, no further options necessary.